# Strip SSL from files pulled from outside company - which tool should I use?

Tags: ssl, proxy

I have a legacy application running on an aging Weblogic server. I have noticed that newer SSL certificates does not play well with my old Java and I though of setting up an offload server to handle the requests I do over https to retrieve customer data.

What I am trying to accomplish is to set up a new server that should serve as a https to http tunnel and I was thinking of setting up paths on that server that corresponds to my customers in the following manner:

- Weblogic calls the bridge server with the URL /cust01/path-to-data.
- The bridge then calls the customer's server, using SSL, with the same
  path to data
- The server returns that to Weblogic

Same thing for cust02 and so forth. This would probably require a table of all customers, their alias ("cust02") and the corresponding external URL.

Another way, but here I must admit I am at a total loss, would be to keep the URL from Weblogic but somehow switch http... to https... when it goes through the intermediate server.

I have experimented with apache2 and the mod_proxy but am not sure that I got it right. So far I have managed to pipe local address "foo" to Google but the problem is that the browser I use for testing shows the google page but also changes the URL. It seems as if I get transferred to google and when I tried to access a file on the remote server, I got an error.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Is Apache the right tool or should I search somewhere else?

Comment: What are your requirements? If all you want to do is listen on a single SSL port, and forward all incoming traffic directly (at TCP level) to your single non-SSL server port, then you can use `stunnel` to do so. If you have to understand HTTP (within the SSL pipe), and act accordingly (eg: you have several backend servers, and you want to be able to direct the connection according to some rule, URL or cookie or whatever), then you'll need a reverse proxy (like Apache mod_proxy). Keep in mind that in all cases, you'll lose the direct visibility of the client IP address on your backend servers.

Comment: I do not want to forward all incoming traffic; the whole idea is that the traffic is initiated from the Weblogic server in order to retrieve a file from the customer's site, using the https protocol. My idea was to have a table in the web server where I replace the token "cust01" with the proper address for that particular customer but this was only to accommodate the change in protocol from http (used internally) to https (used from customer to me). This would, of course, require a table with all customers and one other way would be to keep the URL but change the protocol on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the URL change is probably not your fault, and results from Google redirecting you (you ask for `google.com`, they refer you to `google.de` or something like that).
The best way to solve this would by using an HTTP proxy, assuming you have that setting in your application (hopefully you do, as it's pretty common.
Since you need a [forward proxy and not a reverse proxy](http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/87783/Forward-Proxy-vs-Reverse-Proxy) (you're replacing the client and not the server), you shouldn't be worried about issue like client visibility (the server confusing the client).
I'd use nginx since it's significantly faster than Apache and has a cleaner configuration interface.
This post talks about using nginx as a forward proxy, like you should
http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy
The relevant part is this:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass https://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root html;
    }
}
```

Do note that I modified `proxy_pass` to use https as the protocol - meaning this proxy will fail if that target site doesn't use https

Comment: OK, so this solution does not work as the table-of-hosts I had envisioned above, but rather like a proper proxy. In order to use this I will have to set JAVA_FLAGS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<my nginx host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080. Nifty. I just tried it out with Firefox and it worked like a charm. Remains to test it in production.

Comment: @koenig this should be better (IMO) than a static mapping because when the host's URL is modified it's no biggie. By the way, you can try using `curl` instead of firefox as you client, since you'll have less surprises (like redirections)

Comment: I agree that this is a very nice solution but the problem is that this effects all traffic from the server - not just specific URLs. It would therefore hinder legitimate traffic that normally should go on the http protocol and for which there is no SSL solution in place.

Comment: True. You can replace the `$http_host$uri` with hard-coded values, and address the nginx server as the "real" server (instead of a proxy) like you originally intended, if you prefer